# Redirect to a static html page in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React, so this question may make no sense but I want to learn it.

I have index.html page and I want to jump to Components.html page.

**RouteToComponent.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class RouteToComponents extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <a href="Components/Components.html">Components</a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default RouteToComponents;
```

**RouteToComponent.jsx** is called inside **index.jsx**

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import RouteToComponents from './BasicJSX/RouteToComponents.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Hello World!!!
                <RouteToComponents />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

export default App;
```

**components.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Entered Components HTML!!!
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

export default App;
```

But when I click on a tag URL changes but the page remains same.

Comment: Try to read about `react-router` https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: @KostyaTresko do I need to read about ```react-router``` even I am redirecting to a static HTML page.

Comment: Are you serving this other html in any way? Because by default react only serves a single static html.

Comment: @GiorgioZanni not exactly while learning I was making different HTML pages for every topic. But gave me really valuable advice.

Comment: The whole point of using React is to serve a single html page and change its contents using javascript (React handles this). Therefore you create big wrapping components that will be your views (or pages) and conditionally render them when you find a match in your url. You can use react-router for this.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your App.js with Router and define Routes. `<Route />` allows us to define all paths of our Application.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import RouteToComponents from './RouteToComponents.jsx';
import AnyComponent from './AnyComponent';
import App from './App.jsx';

return (
 <Router>
   <RouteToComponents />
   <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
     <Route path="/Components/Components.html" component={AnyComponent} />
   </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

Now in your Component where you want to use Link.
In React `<Link />` is used instead of anchor.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

return (
    <div>
       <Link to="Components/Components.html">Components</Link>
       <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    </div>
 );
```

to in Link attribute is similar to href in anchor.

Remember:

1. npm i react-router-dom
2. to attribute of Link must be similar to the path defined in App.js Route. 
   Because when you click on Link it matches Routes in App.js